# Convert 360 days calendar into normal Julian day calendar using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas data frame which looks like below with 30 days in each month. Now I would like to convert this data frame into the regular Julian days calendar and put NA in those days with the missing date (for eg 1/31/2001: NA and so on) and interpolate later. Can any one suggest me the option to handle in pandas ?

```
 Date   X    
1/1/2001    30.56787109
1/2/2001    29.57751465
1/3/2001    30.38424683
1/4/2001    28.64764404
1/5/2001    27.54763794
......
......
1/29/2001   27.44857788
1/30/2001   27.16296387
2/1/2001    28.02816772
2/2/2001    28.28137207
2/3/2001    28.38671875
.......
.......
02/29/2001  32.23730469
02/30/2001  32.56161499
3/1/2001    31.38146973
3/2/2001    30.73623657
3/3/2001    30.81912231
......
3/28/2001   33.7562561
3/29/2001   34.46350098
3/30/2001   33.49130249
4/1/2001    30.91223145
4/2/2001    30.94335938
.....
4/30/2001   30.02526855

......
......
12/29/2001  27.44161987
12/30/2001  28.43597412
```

Comment: Check jdcal library:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jdcal

Comment: IIUC you can first convert the date to datetime `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`, set this to index and then reindex `df.set_index('Date').reindex(pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1])`

Comment: What should be done with February 30?  Which, even in a leap year does not exist...

Comment: For time being, we can ignore Feb 30

Comment: @ EdChum I tried with your method but all data appears to be NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm assuming that your Date column is just a string and is not an index.  And I'm also replacing X with an integer value to make it easier to track what's happening to it.  So first, convert to datetime, and set as index.

```
>>> df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date,errors='coerce')
>>> df = df.set_index('Date')

2001-02-27  10
2001-02-28  11
NaT         12
NaT         13
2001-03-01  14
2001-03-02  15
```

So that uses python/pandas built in time awareness to identify invalid dates (Feb 29 in a non-leap year and Feb 30 in any year).

Then you can just resample to get the index onto a valid calendar.  You also have some fill options (besides the default NaN) with resample or you can interpolate later on.

```
>>> df=df.resample('d')

2001-01-29   3
2001-01-30   4
2001-01-31 NaN
2001-02-01   5
2001-02-02   6
...

2001-02-27  10
2001-02-28  11
2001-03-01  14
2001-03-02  15
```

Comment: @jezrael I was assuming poster really mean Gregorian (based on the "regular" qualifier) and that pandas is doing this automatically?  I'll leave it as is for now but thanks for the suggestion and I'll change it if the poster clarifies that's what he want.  Not 100% clear to me either way...

Answer (score 0):

First, set the column type as a **pandas.Datetimeindex** and then use the **to_julian_date()** function. You can then use the **interpolate()** method to get the in between dates that are missing.

Source:

- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_julian_date.html
- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html